# Can capabilities be specified in Debian packages?

Tags: packaging, capabilities, deb

Since [RPM 4.7](http://www.rpm.org/wiki/Releases/4.7.0#POSIX.1edraft15filecapabilities), there has been the ability to specify that a file in an RPM package should be installed with capabilities set (via `%caps`).

Is there a similar feature for Debian packages?

Comment: Bob - Braiam removed those tags, I'd recommend making this 2 Q's which is where I think he was trying to direct you. Don't just blindly roll back a edit, ask if you're not sure why someone did something.

Comment: @slm: Aha, ok I didn't see the point. Thanks

Comment: Feels awfully close to a duplicate question, though, since cpack can generate RPM and DEB packages.

Comment: It's OK, I'm blessing you to do this. I like these 2 topics as separate since you're more likely to get an answer to this one here, the other one maybe. 8-). BTW you can call out this Q in the other one if that makes you feel better to maintain a relationship w/ each other.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sadly, no. There isn't a way to make `dpkg` use file capabilities, and apparently nobody has ever asked, though the library itself [is available](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=70044).

I skimmed through the [Debian Policy Manual](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/), and there isn't a single entry that reference this feature. That said, you can use `dh_override_install` (if you use `debhelper`), pre/post maintainer scripts or modifying the [`debian/rules`](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-source.html#s-debianrules) file to reproduce this behavior, but I don't see any obviously easy way to implement it.

Comment: This is why I was asking about `cmake`/`cpack`. I was hoping for a way to do this in my cpack rules that would work for both `RPM` and `DEB`. If I do it in maintainer scripts I have to do it twice, or at least arrange for the same maintainer script to be used by both package types. I'll file a bug, thanks. By the way, I couldn't find any mention of this in any `RPM` documentation either, other than the release notes referenced above. So perhaps the `Debian Policy Manual` is similarly not definitive.

Comment: @BobDoolittle actually the Debian Policy Manual *is definitive*. Everything has to be done as the Policy says or may not be included in Debian (it could be even removed), and there are tools that verify this (lintian), but that doesn't mean that it can't be updated. I would add the link to the bug report so people can keep track of it.

Comment: Interesting. This may not be the best place for it (in which case somebody can comment/suggest a better one), but I filed a bug on this issue here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/software-center/+bug/1371695

Comment: @BobDoolittle I would report this upstream (Debian) since Canonical just import upstream policies and barely implement feature requests (unless is enabling a flag).

Comment: That's a good point. Canonical is OK for bug fixes, but not the right place for what is more of a feature request. I'll try https://www.debian.org/Bugs/